# Application of differentiation question

Tags: calculus, derivatives

It is given in question that, 
"Based on the given function, find the critical number,inflection point,intervals where $f(x)$ is increasing and decreasing,interval where $f(x)$ is concave upward and downwards, as well as the local minimum and maximum.Find also any vertical,horizontal or slanting asymptotes.Sketch the following graphs."

a) $f(x)= x/(x-2)$

b)$f(x)= tan^-1 (x^2)$

For (a), I already find out the vertical asymptotes which is x=2 and horizontal asymptotes which is y=1 but however I am stuck when going for the critical number,which is from the first derivatives as $(x-2)^2$ when equal to 0 are equivalent to does not exist.

And for (b) I completely have no idea on this one

Comment: For part (a), you're on the right track with the critical number. The derivative of $f$ is given by $$f'(x)=\dfrac{-2}{(x-2)^2},$$ which is *never* equal to zero, i.e. no solution exists. There is no critical number. For part (b), you need to know how to take the derivative of $\tan^{-1}(u)$ and use the chain rule.

Comment: @Brody hi there!thanks for replying!i understood on the first one,while the second one on $$f(x)=arctan (x^2)$$ I thought i'm getting the true answer to the inflection point,which I can find from the second derivatives but it is contradictory to what the graph of $$f(x)=arctan (x^2)$$ (which I checked on wolfram alpha) in which the graph from wolfram says that the inflection point is at $$x=0$$ and is different from me(which i got in fourth root);Or is the graph don't have the inflection point,and what necessarily mean at the point(in fourth root that I found)?

Comment: The $x=0$ that you're seeing on the plotted graph is a **local minimum**, not a point of inflection. It's just a "valley". A point of inflection is where the function changes concavity, and that doesn't happen at $x=0$.

Comment: If you set the second derivative equal to zero and correctly found the solution, then those are your points of inflection. They mark where the function changes from "concave down" to "concave up" or vice-versa.